# How to use helpers in pry-byebug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry, byebug, binding.pry

In the rails console, we can prepend `helper.` to helpers to use them, like so:

```
helper.time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 60*60*2)
```

but this doesn't work in the server console during a `pry-byebug` debugging

How can I use a method like `time_ago_in_words` after starting debugging with `binding.pry`?

Answer (score 0):

To test helper into console or debugger(i'm not 100% sure) try with:

```rb
ApplicationController.helpers.time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 60*60*2)
```